# Cognitive face API Python 3.5. Bad Image

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import sys
import os, time
import cognitive_face as CF
import global_variables as global_var
import urllib
import sqlite3
import requests
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)


Key = global_var.key

CF.Key.set(Key)

BASE_URL = global_var.BASE_URL  # Replace with your regional Base URL
CF.BaseUrl.set(BASE_URL)

def get_person_id():
    person_id = ''
    extractId = str(sys.argv[1])[-2:]
    connect = sqlite3.connect("Face-DataBase")
    c = connect.cursor()
    cmd = "SELECT * FROM Students WHERE ID = " + extractId
    c.execute(cmd)
    row = c.fetchone()
    person_id = row[3]
    connect.close()
    return person_id

if len(sys.argv) is not 1:
    currentDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    imageFolder = os.path.join(currentDir, "dataset/" + str(sys.argv[1]))
    person_id = get_person_id()
    for filename in os.listdir(imageFolder):
        if filename.endswith(".jpg"):
            print(filename)
            imgurl = urllib.request.pathname2url(os.path.join(imageFolder, filename))
            imgurl = imgurl[3:]
            print("imageurl = {}".format(imgurl))
            res = CF.face.detect(imgurl)
            if len(res) != 1:
                print("No face detected in image")
            else:
                res = CF.person.add_face(imgurl, global_var.personGroupId, person_id)
                print(res)  
            time.sleep(6)
else:
    print("supply attributes please from dataset folder")
```

```
A:\microsoft api FaceRecognition-Attendance-Marking-master>python add_person_faces.py user97
User.97.1.jpg
imageurl = A:/microsoft%20api%20FaceRecognition-Attendance-Marking-master/dataset/user97/User.97.1.jpg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "add_person_faces.py", line 42, in <module>
    res = CF.face.detect(imgurl)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cognitive_face\face.py", line 41, in detect
    'POST', url, headers=headers, params=params, json=json, data=data)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cognitive_face\util.py", line 105, in request
    error_msg.get('message'))
cognitive_face.util.CognitiveFaceException: Error when calling Cognitive Face API:
        status_code: 400
        code: InvalidURL
        message: Invalid image URL.
```

Comment: go through this [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'm sure you can add some description...